# Automatic label updates

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I'm using ChartJs for a small project in a daughnut form. Of course when you de-select a label the chart adjust itself, but I want that my numbers are automaticaly updated too.
I put everything in % and I want that if a label is removed, it live updates itself.
Here is my current code :

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: [
      "Marche",
      "Course",
      "Natation",
      "Vélo"
    ],
    datasets: [{
      data: [65.45, 10, 10, 14.55],
      backgroundColor: [
        "#00ff00",
        "#008fb3",
        "#ff0000",
        "#ffff00",
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var allData = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data;
          var tooltipLabel = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
          var tooltipData = allData[tooltipItem.index];
          var total = 0;
          for (var i in allData) {
            total += allData[i];
          }
          var tooltipPercentage = Math.round((tooltipData / total) * 100);
          return tooltipLabel + ': ' + tooltipData + ' %';
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Récapitulatif des séances de sport',
      fontColor: "#000"
    },

    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        fontColor: '#000',
      }

    }
  }
});
```

```css
.graphsize {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid black 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
body {
  margin-left: 27%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.js"></script>
<div class="graphsize">

  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

I'm a beginner with this api so please explain me how to do this.

Tristan

Comment: Consider linking the Chart.js library in your snippet, it will allow the chart to generate IIRC.

Comment: Is there a way that I can add it ? I'm pretty new here

Comment: Use a CDN and link to the script file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike with line charts the doughnut chart is not hiding datasets when you click on the legend so you can't use the helper method `chart.isDatasetVisible` but you can access the meta data chartjs uses internally about the data points to find out if it is hidden

`data.datasets[DATASET_INDEX]._meta[0].data[DATA_ITEM_INDEX].hidden`

using this in the loop which creates the total you can exclude any data items that are hidden

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: [
      "Marche",
      "Course",
      "Natation",
      "Vélo"
    ],
    datasets: [{
      data: [65.45, 10, 10, 14.55],
      backgroundColor: [
        "#00ff00",
        "#008fb3",
        "#ff0000",
        "#ffff00",
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var allData = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data;
          var tooltipLabel = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
          var tooltipData = allData[tooltipItem.index];
          var total = 0;
          for (var i in allData) {
            if (!data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex]._meta[0].data[i].hidden) {
              total += allData[i];
            }

          }
          var tooltipPercentage = Math.round((tooltipData / total) * 100);

          return tooltipLabel + ': ' + tooltipPercentage + ' %';
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Récapitulatif des séances de sport',
      fontColor: "#000"
    },

    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        fontColor: '#000',
      }

    }
  }
});
```

```css
.graphsize {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid black 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
body {
  margin-left: 27%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.js"></script>
<div class="graphsize">

  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Quite alright, if this answers your question you can mark it as the answer or if it doesn't leave the question as unanswered/ update your question with what you are looking for